# What is an easy way to verify LDAP login credentials on a local Solaris system

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, credentials

I have an application that needs to execute some functions only if user has credentials that can log into the local (Solaris) system. I just need a quick way to verify the credentials. This does not work. It just executes with no error and no printout.

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"); 
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://hostname"); 
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
LdapContext ldapContext;

Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>(env); 
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "username");
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "");
DirContext context;
try {
    context = LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance("ldap://HOSTNAME", environment);
    System.out.println("Seccess");
} catch (NamingException ex) {
    System.out.println("Authentication failed: " + ex);
    Logger.getLogger(FAMENewReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information about your environment for any information to be provided. Is LDAP even present on ldap://hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this worked. Notice the use of doman\username, instead of just username.

```
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"); 
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx"); 
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "domain\\username");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "passwd");
    try {
        DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
        System.out.println("Success");
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Authentication failed: " + ex);
    }
```